# Generating random numbers using LCG method

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 using the LCG method but it keeps giving me the error "local variable 's' referenced before assignment" How do I fix it without using a global variable?

```
def set_seed(S):
    return S
def pseudo():
    S = (S*a + c) % m/m
    return S
m = 233280 # modulus
a = 9301 # multiplier
c = 49297 # increment
set_seed(1234)
VALUE_1 = pseudo()
set_seed(4321)
VALUE_2 = pseudo()
print(VALUE_1)
print(VALUE_2)
```

Comment: What's the initial value of `S`?

Comment: What's set_seed?

Comment: In the line `S = (S*a + c) % m/m` you multiple `S`, but have not initialized it yet. That is what is meant with `local variable 's' referenced before assignment`

Comment: What is the initial value of S,a, c and m

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I wanted to obtain different random numbers (VALUE_1 and VALUE_2) using the different initial values of S (1234 and 4321). When I set a value of S before the line 'S = (S*a + c) % m/m', it returns the same numbers for VALUE_1 and VALUE_2. What should I do?